# Grails Spring Security verificar se Usuário pertence a Grupo (RoleGroup)

Tags: spring-security, grails

Eu tenho as seguintes classes de domínio:

User *hasOne* RoleGroup *hasMany* Role

- **Exemplos:**

**RoleGroup**: Admin, Profissional, Cliente, ...

**Role**: ROLE_ACTION_1, ROLE_ACTION_2, ...

Como faço para verificar se o Usuário pertence a um RoleGroup específico?

No @Secured só consigo inserir "ROLE"... Será que eu preciso incluir todas as ROLEs do grupo sempre que eu quiser conceder acesso a um grupo especifico? Tem uma forma viável de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente quando você usa o comando do plugin para gerar as classes são geradas classes Usuario, Perfil, UsuarioPerfil.

```
    grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp Usuario Perfil
```

Nesta terceira existe um método estático chamado: get(long usuarioId, long perfilId), sua chamada seria assim.

```
    UsuarioPerfil.get(usuario.id, perfil.id)
```

Caso exista ele retorna um objeto UsuarioPerfil que é relação entre os dois, Usuário + Perfil.